# Laravel WebCam doesn't work on local server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a function that opens the webcam when a button is pressed on, everything works fine when I do `php artisan serve` but upon trying to run the same application on my local IP address that same button doesn't work anymore and throws an error. So for example by doing `php artisan serve --host=192.168.10.10` I get the following error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia')**

Here's the a sample of the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openCamera()">Open camera</button>

<div id="cameraContainer">
    <video id="cameraVideo" style="display: none;"></video>
    <div id="overlayFrame"></div>
    <canvas id="photoCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
        var videoStream;

        function openCamera() {
            // Access the camera
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    video: true
                })
                .then(function(stream) {
                    videoStream = stream;
                    var video = document.getElementById('cameraVideo');
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                    video.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('overlayFrame').style.display = 'block';
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error('Error accessing camera: ', error);
                });
        }
    </script>
```

I wonder if the browser explicitly saying `not secure` has anything to do with the reason why it doesn't work
I tried `php artisan serve --host=192.168.10.10 --port=443` but that also didn't work and I got this error :

**An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

Comment: It does state on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) - `"This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers."`

Comment: I guessed it that's why I tried with the https port. I need a way to bypass that by maybe making the address secured

Comment: Create your own certificate and configure the server to use that. No idea how to use Laravel and it's associated methods but openssl has all you need to generate a self-signed certificate for development use

Comment: Make sure that APP_URL in .env is correct when changing to ip.